# How to go back to the middle of the road after turn in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

My code is about 2 car in one road, where both cars will change their heading (turn to left) if they meet head-to-head, and go back to the center of the road **(which is pycor = 0)** and turtles can't walk outside the road,

My problem is I **don't know how to make the turtles move back to the center,** I tried to use cohesion from flocking, but I don't know the right way. Here is my code:

```
globals
[initialHead too-close-distance]

turtles-own
[speed
top-speed]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [setup-road]
  setup-cars
  reset-ticks
end

to go

 move

end


to setup-road
   if pycor < 2 and pycor > -2 [ set pcolor white
  ]
end

to setup-cars
  create-turtles 1
  [
    setxy -15 0
    set color red
    set size 1.2
    set initialHead 90

    set speed 0.5
    set top-speed 0.5 + random-float 0.5

  ]

  create-turtles 1
  [
    setxy 15 -0
    set color blue
    set size 1.2
    set initialHead 270

    set speed 0.5
    set top-speed 0.5 + random-float 0.5

  ]
end

to move
  ask turtles
  [
  speed-up-car
  avoid
  forward speed]
end

to avoid
  slow-down-car
  let visibility (patches in-cone 7 50)
  let center pycor = 0
  let too-near one-of other turtles-on visibility

  ifelse too-near != nobody

  [turn-away ([heading] of too-near) max-separate-turn
  [;need to turn back to center]
   [ fd speed]

end


to turn-away [new-heading max-turn]
  turn-at-most (subtract-headings heading new-heading) max-turn
end

to turn-at-most [turn max-turn]  ;; turtle procedure
  ifelse abs turn > max-turn
    [ ifelse turn > 0
        [ rt max-turn ]
        [ lt max-turn ] ]
    [ rt turn ]
end

to speed-up-car
  set speed (speed + acceleration)
  if speed > top-speed [ set speed top-speed ]
end

to slow-down-car
  set speed (speed - deceleration)
  if speed < 0 [ set speed deceleration ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some basic logic that I think will work for passing for the case of 2 cars heading opposite directions.  The logic gets much more complex if you have many cars.

I'll leave it to you to write NetLogo code.

Basically, you need a state-transition plans which keeps track of what state each car is in, so it can decide what to do next and what state that will put it in.

Suppose you have states ["driving", "turning-away", "passing", "turning-back" ],   and you know if you have conflicting traffic.    You also know your y-position so you know how far off the center you are.

You need to figure out logically what all the possible and relevant transitions are and the rules that determine which one to take given what state you are currently in.

It would be interesting (!) to model the states as nodes and the transitions as links, but let's leave that for another time.

Basically you will end up with a long list of if-else clauses, which you can evaluate to decide what the next-state will be, and then after everything is evaluated, you can do what it takes to move to that state.  Rather than building a full dynamic model of motion, let's simplify to say that passing involves turning to 10 degrees from the original heading for a bit, then by 30 degrees for a while, then by 10 degrees for a while longer, then back to 0 degrees when happily off the road.   Returning to the center-line is just the reverse process.   This would probably look ok to a user.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
if driving and there's no conflict, keep driving.

if driving  [
   if there's a conflict 
[ set next-state "turning-away" 
       if off-road by short distance [set offset-angle 10]
       if off-road by medium distance [ set offset-angle 30]
       if off-road by large distance [ set offset-angle 10]
       if off-road entirely [ set offset-angle 0 set state "passing"]
]
otherwise [ set next-state "driving"]
and move forward based on speed and heading.

if in the middle of turning away the conflict goes away, i don't know what you want to do.   Probably completing move to the passing location is simplest to code.

if passing and there's still a conflict, keep on passing

if passing and there's no conflict anymore, reverse the moves based on distance off-road to get back on the road.

if in the middle of turning back there is a new conflict, i don't know what you want to do.   Probably change to turning-away and pick a heading based on distance from the centerline as above.
```

Anyway, let me know what you think of that approach.  I don't see how to make it much simpler.

Comment: Yes, this is something that I had in mind to do, but coding it using Netlogo is a challenge to me, thanks for making it clearer to me :D